# Programar para Mac Os X usando Windows

Tags: macos

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio para Windows usando Visual .Net y una base de datos en MySQL. Aparte de los Windows se utiliza también en varios Macs mediante Fusion.
Ahora me han pedido que haga desde cero algunos módulos para poder usarla en los Macs directamente y así olvidarme de la virtualización. Si es posible programaría en mi PC Windows ya que los Macs están todos en uso.
Estoy aprovechando mis días de vacaciones para poder averiguar por dónde comenzar, agradezco vuestra ayuda!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es muy amplia, dices que necesitas programar para macOS desde Windows en ambiente .Net. Sin embargo, me temo que eso no sería posible. Son 2 sistemas totalmente diferentes, para empezar. La única forma de programar nativamente para macOS es usar macOS. Saludos

Comment: Necesitas Xcode.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Gracias por tu respùesta, pero seguramente no me he explicado bien. Leeré tus recomendaciones ;)

Comment: @Bicho Por lo que poco que he leído hasta ahora veo que por ahí van los tiros. Muchas gracias por esa Respuesta Práctica a mi Pregunta!

Comment: XCode sólo corre en ambiente macOS. Como dije en mi comentario, programar para macOS sólo será posible (hasta donde yo conozco) en un ambiente macOS. Puedes virtualizar macOS en tu host Windows, aunque imagino que debes poseer de buenos recursos para que la virtualización se comporte con cierta soltura. Otra opción es hacer un *hackintosh*, y otra es usar *MacInCloud*. Pero directamente desde Windows desarrollar algo para macOS (nativo) no lo veo posible. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @MauricioContreras, intentaré usar XCode en una maquina virtual y si no apañarme un Mac. Por otro lado entiendo que sea una pregunta demasiado amplia pero cuando uno desconoce el tema no le queda otra que poner qué necesita y a base de comentar se va concretando... No soy de ir poniendo preguntas (llevo ya un tiempo en Stack y solo he puesto 2 porque el 99% de las veces he encontrado la respuesta) pero en este tema iba muy perdido. Gracias por vuestro tiempo de nuevo!

Answer (score 0):

Os comento qué he hecho por si le sirve a alguien:

He instalado VmWare Pro 15 en mi Windows 10 y he creado una maquina Mac OS X Mojave.
Después he instalado Xcode 11.3.1 y me encuentro aprendiendo Swift desde cero.

Saludos!